# Conteúdo não é mostrado após clique

Tags: jquery

Fiz uma **li** que quando clicado, deve mostrar o conteúdo presente dentro de uma **div** que está como **visibility:hidden**.
Como estou chamando o JS.

```js
 $(".buttonShowContentSinopse").click(function() {
   $(".showContentSinopse").show();
 });
```

```css
.showContentSinopse {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContent">
  <ul>
    <li class="buttonShowContentSinopse active">Sinopse</li>
    <li>Ficha Ténica</li>
    <li>Imagens</li>
    <li>Trailer</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="showContentSinopse grid_475 float-left padding-20 bgYellow">
    <p>Num futuro próximo, o combustível que alimenta os motores dos carros é também motivo para crimes perpretados por violentas gangues. Max é um jovem policial e junto com seus companheiros patrulha as estradas a fim de impedir a ação daqueles que insistem
      em perturbar a paz. A morte de um membro pelas mãos de Max dá início a uma série de crimes cruéis cometidos contra sua família e o melhor amigo. Assim, Max só tem uma escolha: vingança.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você está usando .hide () ?? Se é pra aparecer use o .show(), você deve ter invertido os papeis .

Comment: Eu confundi na hora de colocar o código aqui. Mas, com **show** também não funciona.

Comment: Cara no seu CSS  troque , coloque display : none ao invés de visibility : hidden

Comment: Aparece esse erro no console: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Seu HTML

```
    <div class="boxContent">
  <ul>
    <li class="buttonShowContentSinopse active">Sinopse</li>
    <li>Ficha Ténica</li>
    <li>Imagens</li>
    <li>Trailer</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="showContentSinopse grid_475 float-left padding-20 bgYellow">
    <p>Num futuro próximo, o combustível que alimenta os motores dos carros é também motivo para crimes perpretados por violentas gangues. Max é um jovem policial e junto com seus companheiros patrulha as estradas a fim de impedir a ação daqueles que insistem
      em perturbar a paz. A morte de um membro pelas mãos de Max dá início a uma série de crimes cruéis cometidos contra sua família e o melhor amigo. Assim, Max só tem uma escolha: vingança.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Seu CSS

```
.showContentSinopse{
    display:none;
}
```

Seu JS:

```
 $(".buttonShowContentSinopse").click( function() {     
    $(".showContentSinopse").show();    
 });
```

Coloque assim .

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi.
O problema era a versão do JQuery.

Comment: Se você resolveu, apenas marque como respondido, geralmente, apenas se criar uma resposta para responder uma pergunta, abraços bons estudos.

Comment: Onde marco como **respondido**? não conheço essa função do SO.

Comment: Geralmente fica uma barrinha verde , depois que você usa , uma resposta como referência você marca a resposta , procura no em outros post , como a pergunta foi feita por você acho que só você pode colocar .

Comment: @FelipeStoker acho que a melhor maneira seria remover a pergunta.